# Some troubles with parsing zip64

Tags: zip, 7zip

I created zip64 archive by compressing a 6Gb file with deflate algo via 7z. After that I started write my code and faced some issues.

1. It contains "zip64 end of central directory record" of size 44. But it must be bigger, because I have a big file and info about that must be stored in "zip64 extensible data sector" isn't it?
2. Because of first problem I can't find data descriptor, because I don't have size of file (-1 in local file header) and data descriptor doesn't have signature (it is optional).

The main question: is this a correct zip64 or 7z created it badly, and I must make it in other way?

Comment: The observation of hex representation of zip64 archive showed that sometimes this info is written in the extra data of the corresping "central directory file header" (the format is at "zip64 extended information extra field") BUT, sometimes, without offset!